# How to work with nonjson data in swift3.0

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I am facing  some issue with non json data from the backed in swft3.0.

This is the Api I am using http://api.geonames.org/export/geonamesData.js?username=orakzai.

And the response is:

`var geonamesPostalCodeCountries = ["AD","AR","AS","AT","AU","AX","BD","BE","BG","BR","BY","CA","CH","CO","CR","CZ","DE","DK","DO","DZ","ES","FI","FO","FR","GB","GF","GG","GL","GP","GT","GU","HR","HU","IE","IN","IS","IT","JE","JP","LI","LK","LT","LU","MC","MD","MK","MP","MQ","MT","MX","MY","NC","NL","NO","NZ","PH","PK","PL","PM","PR","PT","RE","RO","RU","SE","SI","SK","SM","TH","TR","US","VA","VI","WF","YT","ZA","GR"];
var geonamesUserIpCountryCode='null';`

Please find the below code.

```
callApi(apiName: "http://api.geonames.org/export/geonamesData.js?username=orakzai")    

 func callApi(apiName :String) {
   let reachability = Reachability()
   if !(reachability?.isReachable)! {
       showAlertView(message: " We are unable to reach servers. Please check your network/internet connection.")
   } else {
       let url = URL(string: "\(apiName)")

       let session = URLSession.shared // or let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)

       if let usableUrl = url {
           let task = session.dataTask(with: usableUrl, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
               print(response)
               if let data = data {
                   if let stringData = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                       self.dataArray.append(stringData)
                       print(self.dataArray)
                   }
               }
           })
           task.resume()
       }
   }
```

When I use this code I am getting below response

`["var geonamesPostalCodeCountries = [\"AD\",\"AR\",\"AS\",\"AT\",\"AU\",\"AX\",\"BD\",\"BE\",\"BG\",\"BR\",\"BY\",\"CA\",\"CH\",\"CO\",\"CR\",\"CZ\",\"DE\",\"DK\",\"DO\",\"DZ\",\"ES\",\"FI\",\"FO\",\"FR\",\"GB\",\"GF\",\"GG\",\"GL\",\"GP\",\"GT\",\"GU\",\"HR\",\"HU\",\"IE\",\"IN\",\"IS\",\"IT\",\"JE\",\"JP\",\"LI\",\"LK\",\"LT\",\"LU\",\"MC\",\"MD\",\"MK\",\"MP\",\"MQ\",\"MT\",\"MX\",\"MY\",\"NC\",\"NL\",\"NO\",\"NZ\",\"PH\",\"PK\",\"PL\",\"PM\",\"PR\",\"PT\",\"RE\",\"RO\",\"RU\",\"SE\",\"SI\",\"SK\",\"SM\",\"TH\",\"TR\",\"US\",\"VA\",\"VI\",\"WF\",\"YT\",\"ZA\",\"GR\"];\nvar geonamesUserIpCountryCode=\'null\';\n"]`

I want to `var geonamesPostalCodeCountrie` to `tableview`.

Comment: Is your question about working with the format of the response (which is not a JSON string but simply two variables, one of them is an array)? Or, do you want to know how to put data in a table view.

Comment: Hi Marom Thanks for quick reply,y question is get that array from the response

Comment: Better use this one: http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeCountryInfoJSON?formatted=true&&username=demo&style=full ? From there: http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html

Comment: Added an answer. I would change the question title to something like: "how to parse variables from a javascript code string in swift 3?"

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have the following string variable:

```js
let response = "var geonamesPostalCodeCountries = [\"AD\",\"AR\",\"AS\",\"AT\",\"AU\",\"AX\",\"BD\",\"BE\",\"BG\",\"BR\",\"BY\",\"CA\",\"CH\",\"CO\",\"CR\",\"CZ\",\"DE\",\"DK\",\"DO\",\"DZ\",\"ES\",\"FI\",\"FO\",\"FR\",\"GB\",\"GF\",\"GG\",\"GL\",\"GP\",\"GT\",\"GU\",\"HR\",\"HU\",\"IE\",\"IN\",\"IS\",\"IT\",\"JE\",\"JP\",\"LI\",\"LK\",\"LT\",\"LU\",\"MC\",\"MD\",\"MK\",\"MP\",\"MQ\",\"MT\",\"MX\",\"MY\",\"NC\",\"NL\",\"NO\",\"NZ\",\"PH\",\"PK\",\"PL\",\"PM\",\"PR\",\"PT\",\"RE\",\"RO\",\"RU\",\"SE\",\"SI\",\"SK\",\"SM\",\"TH\",\"TR\",\"US\",\"VA\",\"VI\",\"WF\",\"YT\",\"ZA\",\"GR\"];\nvar geonamesUserIpCountryCode=\'null\';\n"
```

Since in Swift you cannot simply evaluate the response string like in JavaScript, using `eval(response);` (which would have created dynamic variables matching the ones declared in the string), how about this:

```js
let vars = response.components(separatedBy: "\n")

var geonamesPostalCodeCountriesStr = vars[0].components(separatedBy: "=")[1].trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: " [];")).replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")
var geonamesPostalCodeCountries: [String] = geonamesPostalCodeCountriesStr.components(separatedBy: ",")

var geonamesUserIpCountryCodeStr = vars[1].components(separatedBy: "=")[1].trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: " [];")).replacingOccurrences(of: "\'", with: "")
var geonamesUserIpCountryCode: String? = (geonamesUserIpCountryCodeStr == "null") ? nil : geonamesUserIpCountryCodeStr
```